# Differences and relations between $T_1$ and $T_2$ topologies

Tags: general-topology

So I thought about the following questions as I am learning about $T_1$ and $T_2$ topologies.

What are the properties that is shared among $T_1$ and $T_2$ topologies? What are the properties that isn't shared among $T_1$ and $T_2$ ?

One thing I can definitely see is that any $T_2$ topologies are in fact $T_1$, also any finite set in $T_1$ will be closed in $T_1$, which we can easily proven, so any finite set in $T_2$ will be also closed.

Is the following correct? Any $T_1$ topology with the fact that every sequence converges to at most one point is $T_2$?

Comment: The notion of a convergent sequence is not applicable to all spaces.

Comment: @user254665 It is. Recall the definition: a sequence $(x_n)$ (in a space $X$) converges to $x \in X$ iff for every open set $O$ that contains $x$, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $x_n \in O$. Just defined in terms of open sets, no extra conditions needed. We can always talk about convergence of sequences (or nets).

Comment: Yes of course. I  just meant to give a warning . In some spaces, such as $\beta N\backslash N$, convergent sequences are necessarily trivial in that they must be eventually constant.Many students start with metric spaces,and when they take on general topology,some of them tend to stick with the  definitions from metric theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not correct. Let $Y$ be any uncountable set, and let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points not in $Y$. Let $X=Y\cup\{p,q\}$, and let

$$\tau=\{U\subseteq X:p,q\notin U\text{ or }X\setminus U\text{ is countable}\}\;.$$

Then $\tau$ is a $T_1$ topology on $X$ that is not $T_2$, since $p$ and $q$ do not have disjoint open nbhds. However, the only convergent sequences in $X$ are the trivial ones, i.e., that ones that are eventually constant, so every convergent sequence has a unique limit point.

**Added:** One interesting way of seeing just how much stronger $T_2$ is than $T_1$ is to compare the following characterizations, both of which are quite easy to prove. Let $X$ be a space, and for each $x\in X$ let $\mathscr{B}_x$ be the family of open nbhds of $x$.

- $X$ is $T_1$ if and only if $\bigcap_{B\in\mathscr{B}_x}B=\{x\}$.
- $X$ is $T_2$ if and only if $\bigcap_{B\in\mathscr{B}_x}\operatorname{cl}B=\{x\}$.

Comment: what conditions can we add to $T_1$ in order to lift it to be $T_2$?

Comment: @Karim: I don’t know of anything that isn’t essentially just a paraphrase of the definition. However, there’s a way of looking at these two separation axioms that may be along the lines that you’re after; hang on a couple of minutes, and I’ll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer yeah this is exactly what I was looking for..

Comment: @Karim: One can prove that a space is $T_2$ if and only if it is both $T_1$ and [$R_1$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R1_space), though that isn't very revealing....

Comment: @Karim: You’re welcome.